# Silverlight app debugging when used WCF RIA and Entity Framework

Tags: silverlight-4.0, entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I am working on an app where I am using WCF RIA services and entity framework.

On laod,i have written a method which gets a list of schedules from database(as fetched using RIA method LoadOperation<>).

I have put a breakpoint on the method,but when I debug it the list shows 0 count and when I bind the empty list to datagrid,the grid shows all records.

How's this possible.

I got stuck in between

Kindly help for the same!!!

Answer (score 2):

Loading data via the DomainContext is an asynchronous operation. Binding to a grid, etc. works because LoadOperation.Entities is observable and will fill in eventually. However, if you're trying to access it in code, you will have to wait for the callback.

```
myContext.Load(myContext.GetMyQuery(), OnLoadCompleted, null);

private void OnLoadCompleted(LoadOperation<MyEntity> op)
{
    if (op.HasError)
    {
        // Handle error
        op.MarkErrorAsHandled();
    }
    else
    {
        IEnumerable<MyEntity> entities = op.Entities;
        // now do stuff with entities
    }
}
```

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707370%28v=VS.91%29.aspx) for more information.